# Inserting Missing Dates into Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports 10.

In my database I have production values for each Date. There's a date column and a qty column. When I run a report on this the dates on the report correspond to the dates in the database, but I'd like the report to display every date and if there is no value for it a 0. Is this possible to do right in the report?

The date is a group field with detail suppressed. The numeric values are a sum of the details placed in the group header, if that makes a difference.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 questions.

1. To display a 0 for null values, you can go into your options menu and "convert database NULL values to default"
   Alternatively, you can use make a new formula with this code and use `if isnull({Table1.Amount}) then 0 else {Table1.Amount}`. I recommend this option since it won't affect other fields in the report.
2. To display *every* date, you should make a 'helper/index' table in your datasource and right-join your actual data to it.  Crystal can't display data for, say, 01/07/2010 if there are no records for it.

Comment: I cannot change anything in the database. I found this here: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1323926&page=392 but the instructions were a little too complicated for me to adjust to what I need. It does give the indication that I can use Crystal to add dates that are missing from the database.

Comment: (I can't speak for that other thread you found. It might work, it might not). Lucky for you, Crystal accepts input from multiple different databases. So make your 'helper' table in an Access DB or even an Excel file. This helper table will serve as the 'index' of your report, i.e. everything else right-joins to it.  Once these dates are in there, use the Report Selection Formula editor to limit it just the dates of interest, i.e. all of 2010.

Comment: I've tried using the helper table route. I've made an excel spreadsheet and added it to my report and linked the fields. However, right outer join is grayed out. I added a picture to my question illustrating my current setup. After reading about JOINS it appears left join should work also, but it's not. The only dates appearing in the report are the dates from the original database. the 'extras' from the spreadsheet are not appearing.

Comment: Would the fact that the field type of the excel field is DateTime as reported by CR whereas the field type of the database field is Date have something to do with it?

Comment: Almost there.  Try changing the Grouping field from {TransactionDate} to {Sheet1_.F1}. If you are still having problems, try changing the "Enforce Join" to "Not Enforced".

Comment: I think I've figured out why the extra dates aren't showing. I had other parameters in my Select Expert. {IM1_InventoryMasterfile.ProductLine} = "C" and
{IM5_TransactionDetail.TransactionDate} = {?Pm-?Dates} and
{IM5_TransactionDetail.TransactionCode} in ["WI", "WR"]
I don't know how change that to accept null values though so it will include the dates where product line and transcode are null, the extra dates.